# What's the difference between /private/etc/apache2 and /etc/apache2?

Tags: apache-http-server

Both of these directories are in 10.7 OSX, but I have no idea which httpd.conf I should be editing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the standard Lion configuration /etc is a symlink to /private/etc so you're really dealing with the same Apache configuration directory.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was going to suggest using http://serverfault.com/a/155131 as the long way around.